# private message using websockets

Tags: php, websocket

How can we implement a private message system (client to client) using Websockets (and PHP)?

From what I understood, the server broadcasts the message and all of the clients can receive the message through connection.onmessage event handler. I was wondering if there is a way to send the message to only a targeted user in the websockets?

Comment: I have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592513/websocket-message-to-specific-user , but there is no answer to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a client sends a messages (`ws.send( message );`) your WebSocket server will receive the message. The sockets that then you send that on to is determined entirely by your server code - your implementation.

To create a one-to-one chat you need a way of routing data between just the two clients involved in the chat. You also need a way of authenticating that only those two clients can receive that information.

WebSocket frameworks tend to provide an additional [PubSub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) layer e.g. Pusher (who I previously worked for) do this using [channels](http://pusher.com/docs/channels). You will find similar terminology along with 'subjects' and 'topics'.

Once you have a way of routing data (chat messages) between just two clients you then need to consider authenticating the subscription. More information can be found on that via this question which asks [How do I create Private channel between two user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406580/39904). The question is about Ruby but is applicable to any technology.

Comment: Thanks Leggetter. It seems implementing the solution using socket.io and node.js is easier.

Comment: socket.io isn't the only option and I'd recommend you have a look at alternatives. For PHP there's [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) and [Wrench](https://github.com/varspool/Wrench). However, they don't offer fallbacks when WebSockets are not present. If you are looking at node.js then have a look at [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/). If you would like to stick with PHP and want connection fallbacks then Pusher is a good solution.